# How to get C# async methods to actually run in parallel?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have never used `async` methods before, but I found myself building a monitoring tool and thought that I could use this type of methods to speed things up.

The tool defines a list of **SiteConfigurations**, and each **SiteConfiguration** has a list of **Monitors** to be tested (via HTTP requests). The architecture of the tool is pipeline based, so for example:

- when a monitor succeeds, the `MonitorSuccessPipeline` is executed
- when a monitor fails, the `MonitorFailurePipeline` is executed
- when all monitors within a site configuration have run, the `SiteAfterMonitorsPipeline` is executed
- when all site configurations have run, the `EndEnginePipeline` is executed

The initial approach was to loop through all `SiteConfigurations` and, for each of them, run all associated `Monitors`.

Total execution time: 100 SiteConfigurations x 4 Monitors x ~1 second per monitor = ~400 seconds to run.

So I changed my `RunMonitor` to be `async` (the actual method does more than what you see here, this is the "core" of the method):

```
    private async Task<Result> RunMonitor(Monitor currentMonitor)
    {
        Result result = new Result();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.GetAsync(currentMonitor.TestUrl);
        var content = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        bool containSuccessText = content.Contains(currentMonitor.SuccessText);
        bool isOk = status == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        result.Success = containSuccessText && isOk;

        if (result.Success)
        {
            ExecutePipeline("MonitorSuccessPipeline", currentMonitor);
        }
        else
        {
            ExecutePipeline("MonitorFailurePipeline", currentMonitor);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Next, I have changed the `RunSiteConfigurationMonitors` method to be:

```
    private async Task<Result> RunSiteConfigurationMonitors(SiteConfiguration siteConfig)
    {
        Result result = new Result();
        List<Task<Result>> tasks = new List<Task<Result>>();
        foreach (var currentMonitor in siteConfig.Monitors)
        {
            tasks.Add(RunMonitor(siteConfig, globalConfig, currentMonitor));
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            result.Insert(r.Body);
        }

        ExecutePipeline("SiteAfterMonitorsPipeline", siteConfig);

        return result;
    }
```

Finally, I changed the `RunEngine` method to be:

```
    public async Task RunEngine(string configName)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration globalConfig = GetConfiguration(configName);
        List<Task<Result>> tasks = new List<Task<Result>>();
        foreach (var sc in globalConfig.SiteConfigurations)
        {
            tasks.Add(RunSiteConfigurationMonitors(sc, globalConfig));
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            logger.Insert(r.Body);
        }

        ExecutePipeline("EndEnginePipeline", globalConfig);
    }
```

I expected to see the `RunEngine` method call all the `RunSiteConfigurationMonitors` and see them run in parallel at the same time - and in turn each `RunSiteConfigurationMonitors` call the `RunMonitor` and see those run at the same time.

Instead, this is what was the output on a subset of monitors:

```
[21:56:50.419]: Loading configuration...
[21:56:58.480]: [21:56:52.711]: Monitoring site A
[21:56:58.583]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:52.753]: Found monitor: A1
[21:56:58.687]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:52.753]: Testing URL: http://a1.example.com
[21:56:58.791]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.106]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[21:56:58.894]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.106]: -- Status Code: OK
[21:56:58.997]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.106]: -- Success? True
[21:56:59.100]: [21:56:53.954]: 
[21:56:59.203]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.474]: Found monitor: A2
[21:56:59.306]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.474]: Testing URL: http://a2.example.com
[21:56:59.375]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.761]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[21:56:59.478]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.762]: -- Status Code: OK
[21:56:59.582]: [21:56:53.954]: [21:56:53.762]: -- Success? True
[21:56:59.686]: [21:56:53.954]: 
[21:56:59.790]: 
[21:56:59.894]: [21:56:54.126]: Monitoring site: B
[21:56:59.998]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:54.126]: Found monitor: B1
[21:57:00.101]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:54.126]: Testing URL: http://b1.example.com
[21:57:00.204]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:55.225]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[21:57:00.307]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:55.225]: -- Status Code: OK
[21:57:00.410]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:55.225]: -- Success? True
[21:57:00.515]: [21:56:56.424]: 
[21:57:00.619]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:55.428]: Found monitor: B2
[21:57:00.724]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:55.429]: Testing URL: http://b2.example.com
[21:57:00.827]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:56.254]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[21:57:00.931]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:56.254]: -- Status Code: OK
[21:57:01.036]: [21:56:56.424]: [21:56:56.254]: -- Success? True
[21:57:01.140]: [21:56:56.424]: 
[21:57:01.244]: 
[21:57:01.348]: [21:56:56.597]: Monitoring site: C
[21:57:01.452]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:56.597]: Found monitor: C1
[21:57:01.557]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:56.597]: Testing URL: http://c1.example.com
[21:57:01.662]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:57.219]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[21:57:01.766]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:57.219]: -- Status Code: OK
[21:57:01.869]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:57.219]: -- Success? True
[21:57:01.974]: [21:56:58.206]: 
[21:57:02.078]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:57.418]: Found monitor: C2
[21:57:02.182]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:57.418]: Testing URL: http://c2.example.com
[21:57:02.287]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:58.025]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[21:57:02.392]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:58.025]: -- Status Code: OK
[21:57:02.496]: [21:56:58.206]: [21:56:58.025]: -- Success? True
[21:57:02.602]: [21:56:58.206]: 
[21:57:02.706]:
```

As you can see, the monitors were essentially run in sequential order, and the site configurations also were not run in "parallel".

Were my expectations wrong to begin with, or is my code faulty? Like I said, this is a new world for me, therefore I would *really* appreciate a simple explanation, if possible.

**SOLUTION**

Following Stephen Cleary's suggestion below, I changed the `RunMonitor` to be:

```
    private async Task<Result> RunMonitor(Monitor currentMonitor)
    {
        Result result = new Result();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(currentMonitor.TestUrl);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var status = response.StatusCode;
        bool containSuccessText = content.Contains(currentMonitor.SuccessText);
        bool isOk = status == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        result.Success = containSuccessText && isOk;

        if (result.Success)
        {
            ExecutePipeline("MonitorSuccessPipeline", currentMonitor);
        }
        else
        {
            ExecutePipeline("MonitorFailurePipeline", currentMonitor);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and now it's working in parallel!

```
[23:33:44.199]: Loading configuration...
[23:33:48.968]: [23:33:46.601]: Monitoring site A
[23:33:49.073]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:46.625]: Found monitor: A1
[23:33:49.176]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:46.625]: Testing URL: http://a1.example.com
[23:33:49.281]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:47.047]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[23:33:49.386]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:47.047]: -- Status Code: OK
[23:33:49.490]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:47.047]: -- Success? True
[23:33:49.594]: [23:33:47.637]: 
[23:33:49.667]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:46.692]: Found monitor: A2
[23:33:49.770]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:46.692]: Testing URL: http://a2.example.com
[23:33:49.874]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:47.461]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[23:33:49.978]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:47.461]: -- Status Code: OK
[23:33:50.082]: [23:33:47.637]: [23:33:47.461]: -- Success? True
[23:33:50.186]: [23:33:47.637]: 
[23:33:50.292]: 
[23:33:50.396]: [23:33:46.727]: Monitoring site B
[23:33:50.500]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:46.727]: Found monitor: B1
[23:33:50.604]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:46.727]: Testing URL: http://b1.example.com
[23:33:50.708]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:48.547]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[23:33:50.812]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:48.547]: -- Status Code: OK
[23:33:50.915]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:48.547]: -- Success? True
[23:33:51.019]: [23:33:48.690]: 
[23:33:51.124]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:46.727]: Found monitor: B2
[23:33:51.228]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:46.727]: Testing URL: http://b2.example.com
[23:33:51.332]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:48.336]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[23:33:51.437]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:48.336]: -- Status Code: OK
[23:33:51.541]: [23:33:48.690]: [23:33:48.336]: -- Success? True
[23:33:51.645]: [23:33:48.690]: 
[23:33:51.749]: 
[23:33:51.852]: [23:33:46.728]: Monitoring site C
[23:33:51.956]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:46.728]: Found monitor: C1
[23:33:52.060]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:46.728]: Testing URL: http://c1.example.com
[23:33:52.165]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:47.813]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[23:33:52.271]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:47.813]: -- Status Code: OK
[23:33:52.375]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:47.813]: -- Success? True
[23:33:52.479]: [23:33:48.161]: 
[23:33:52.583]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:46.760]: Found monitor: C2
[23:33:52.688]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:46.760]: Testing URL: http://c2.example.com
[23:33:52.793]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:47.987]: -- Contains success text? Yes
[23:33:52.897]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:47.987]: -- Status Code: OK
[23:33:53.001]: [23:33:48.161]: [23:33:47.987]: -- Success? True
[23:33:53.105]: [23:33:48.161]: 
[23:33:53.208]:
```

I have to admit, though, that I didn't really understand *why* this worked.

Comment: Is this a console application?  Graphical?  Service?  Web app?  Scheduling of tasks varies a lot depending on that.

Comment: The "engine" is going to be executed by a Windows Service, although right now I am executing it from a web page with a "run engine" button

Comment: _"The architecture of the tool is **pipeline** based"_ - glad you got it going.  Check out _[TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)_ - they allow for the creation of pipelines.  Might be useful for something in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the guidelines for asynchronous programming is to not block on asynchronous code. Consider this code in `RunMonitor`:

```
var response = client.GetAsync(currentMonitor.TestUrl);
var content = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The type of `response` is a task, and the next line accesses `Task<T>.Result`, which *synchronously blocks* the method until the HTTP request is complete. So this method is not operating asynchronously. What you probably want is:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(currentMonitor.TestUrl);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Nice pickup - I completely missed that.

Comment: It worked beautifully (see my edit in the post). But I didn't really understand the solution to be honest with you... I thought the await on the second line was there to wait for the response to be available, no?

Comment: @FrancescoGallarotti: `HttpClient` is a bit odd. *By default*, the `GetAsync` will only complete when the entire request has been read, so `ReadAsStringAsync` is not actually asynchronous. You can pass options to the `HttpClient` that cause it to behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are generally correct. The scheduling of the tasks depends on the runtime, whether it is a web application, console application etc. Alternatively, if your application is just a monitoring tool that gets executed per a schedule, you could use `Parallel.ForEach()` set of methods in your `RunEngine()` and `RunSiteConfigurationMonitors` instead of awaiting tasks. Each of your `RunMonitor` would be writing results to a `ConcurrentBag<>`. With `Parallel.ForEach` you could also control the degree of parallelism via `ParallelOptions`, but, again, never more that the number of threads provided by the scheduler. Hope this helps.